# How to change the log level of AWS Lambdas(NodeJS) at runtime?

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, runtime, pinojs

we use pino logger and it looks like this:

```
import pino from 'pino-lambda';


const logger = pino({
    name: 'ac',
    level: process.env.STAGE == 'prod' ? 'info' : 'debug',
    redact: ['password', ]
});

export default logger;
```

How to change the log level of our AWS Lambdas(NodeJS) at runtime?

Comment: Why would you want to change it at runtime and not on init?

Answer (score 1):

```html
class CodelabsLogFormatter implements ILogFormatter {
  format(data: LogData): string {
    return `[employee-service]:[${data.level}] ${JSON.stringify(data)}`;
  }
}
const destination = CodelabsLogFormatter({
  formatter: new KrishLogFormatter(),
});
export const logger = pino(
  {level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info'},
  destination
);
```